# What is the Relationship between signal processing and machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

What is the relationship between signal processing and machine learning?

Is signal processing necessary or helpful before learning Machine learning?

Comment: Also, honestly, the [tag:machine-learning] tag has > 1200 posts. Does that suggest the relationship can be reduced to a short answer here?

Comment: I disagree with the claim that the question has already been answered in. the duplicate.  The duplicate is a question about pedagogy and whether it is OK for an instructor to deviate from the established syllabus for a lab course on DSP and include some machine learning topics/experiments/assignments.  The duplicate  ]and its answer _do not_ address the questions being asked here.